# Proper way to work using the real image of a product on OpenCart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm currently looking for the proper way to work on a theme using the real image of a product and not its thumbnail (identified as `$thumb` in the default theme).

I have found a *abrupt trick* by adding a line in the controller file:

```
$this->data['cover'] = $product_info['image'];
```

But does anybody have experienced a better method (eg with *vqmod*) to retrieve these real image data without changing controller content (for using in template pages, such as `product.tpl` or `category.tpl` for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from [members of OpenCart forum](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=182&t=145313), I managed to find a functional solution (using [vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod)).
It is thus require to create an `.xml` file placed in the `vqmod/xml` folder and containing, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>Recover Real Image</id>
    <version></version>
    <vqmver></vqmver>
    <author></author>
    <email></email>
    <website></website>
    <file name="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            $data['points'] = $product_info['points'];
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            $data['picture'] = HTTP_SERVER.'/image/'.$product_info['image'];
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

If product image can not be found and assuming a `<default.jpg>` is put the root of the `<image>` folder, the `<add>` element can be replaced by:

```
if(empty($product_info['image'])){
    $data['picture'] = HTTP_SERVER.'image/default.jpg';
}
else{
    $data['picture'] = HTTP_SERVER.'image/'.$product_info['image'];
}
```

Other possible suggestions, by using:

- [OCmod](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) can be found [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=182&t=145313#p563030)
- [Image Autosize](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11429) extension can be found [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=182&t=145313#p564402)