# Opencart Vqmod XML load php database variable

Tags: php, xml, opencart, vqmod

I'm trying to create vQmod XML file to avoid editing the core file directly in OpenCart.
One of the XML I wanted to create is load some variables in database which this can be done in PHP but I'm not sure how to call the variable database in XML.

```
example in database
id  name
1   name1
2   name2
3   name3
```

If in PHP I can easily check what is the name of the id. But in XML I dont know how. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking your variable using PHP inside your XML vQmod file, such as:

```
<?php
    if(empty($variable[$id]])){
        # Add a specific condition here
    }
?>
```

As a vQmod file can add operators to your core files, you can use PHP directly in your XML files (see the way I used it [to retrieve the real image of a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433681/) for example).