# Load all images for product without resizing in opencart 2.x

Tags: image, load, opencart2.x

I'm trying to load all images in the product page , but i don't want to resize them.
Does anybody know a simple solution tot do that?
The opencart version is 2.1.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-order to retrieve images without being re-sized on the product page, you **need not** re-size the images in the product controller file.

So in the Product Controller File, locate that in `/catalog/controller/product/product.php`

In the `public function index()`

Look out for `$this->model_tool_image->resize` remove the *function call* and use the link to the image instead to return to the template `HTTPS_SERVER . 'image/'. $image_variable` *provided* **`HTTPS_SERVER`** is defined in `/config.php`

Note: `$image_variable` could be `$product_info['image']` or `$result['image']` , use your best judgement.

Tip: Use `vqmod` as you would be modifying the core controller file

Answer (score 0):

In order to use [vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod) (according to the process described previously), you can take a look to [this method for working with real images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433681/proper-way-to-work-using-the-real-image-of-a-product-on-opencart-2/) instead of thumbnails.

Note that there are other possible suggestions, such as:

- [OCmod](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) which can be found [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=182&t=145313#p563030)
- [Image Autosize](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11429) extension which can be found [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=182&t=145313#p564402)