# Change Image Size on Product Page in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have small problem with changing size of the product image only on product page.

1. I know that from admin I can change the size for all thumb pictures.
2. But how to make bigger images only on the product page and I am not talking about additional images section...
3. Can anyone explain to me where `$thumb` variable is defined as i made search in almost all `php` files but I cannot find `$thumb` declaration...????

In `product.tpl`

Code:

```
<div id="product">
    <div class="a"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="thickbox"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"></a><br>
      <?php echo $text_enlarge; ?></div>
```

Now in this bit taken from `product.tpl` I see that path for the image is taken from the variable called `$thumb`.

I want Opencart to:

1. Prepare for me medium sized image
2. Generate for it path that will be stored in `$medium` variable which I can call in this place and simply have the code like this:

Code:

```
<div id="product">
    <div class="a"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="thickbox"><img src="<?php echo $medium; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"></a><br>
      <?php echo $text_enlarge; ?></div>
```

Anyone please help...

Comment: Another solution could be to work directly with real images and not thumbnails. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30559324/4094098) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start work in opencart, You should have to understand the basic knowledge of opencart **MVC-L** (i.e. How opencart module works)

Here is the [Tutorial](http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2015/10/24/open-cart-tutorial/)

`$thumb` which is defined in `product.tpl` file is declared in its controller file ( `catalog/product/product.php` ) named `$data['thumb']`.

Maximum variables used in product.tpl file are defined in modules controller file.

To more information, Check the above shared tutorial.

Comment: Have you installed any other extension, related to products ?